# System of nonlinear ODE with simple structure

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I have the following system of non-linear ordinary differential equations.

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{dA}{dt} &=& -&\lambda AB + \lambda CD \\
\frac{dB}{dt} &=& -&\lambda AB + \lambda CD \\
\frac{dC}{dt} &=& &\lambda AB - \lambda CD \\
\frac{dD}{dt} &=& &\lambda AB - \lambda CD \\
\end{align}
$$

I know that they are generally difficult to solve analytically but this has a simple structure. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: We have $dA/dt=dB/dt$ and $dC/dt=dD/dt$ therefore $A=B+c_1$ and $C=D+c_2$

Comment: And $\frac{dA}{dt}+\frac{dC}{dt}=0$, so that $A+C=c_3$,...

Comment: Where does this come from? Chemistry?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Biology. I try to model 2 linked genes over time. Each gene has 2 loci. $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ represent all 4 possible combinations of the two genes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From sums and differences of the equations you find that $B=A+b$, $C=-A+c$, $D=-A+d$ with constants $b,c,d$ determined by the initial conditions, so that in consequence the only remaining DE is
$$
\frac{dA}{dt}=−λ(A(A+b)-(A-c)(A-d))=−λ(A(b+c+d)-cd)
$$
which is now a linear DE with constant coefficients, thus easy to solve.

Answer (score 0):

notice $$\frac{d(A+C)}{dt}=0,\frac{d(B+D)}{dt}=0$$ thus there exists constants $a,b$ $$C=A-a,D=B-b$$ now lets we notice: $$\frac{d(A)}{dt}=\frac{d(B)}{dt}=-b\lambda A -a\lambda B +ab\lambda$$ and lets define: $$A'=A-ab\lambda t, B'=B-ab\lambda t$$ then:$$\frac{d(A')}{dt}=\frac{d(B')}{dt}=-b\lambda A -a\lambda B$$ which is a linear ode